# How to add text and icon inside the omnibox to the right

Tags: microsoft-edge-extension

I've done a lot of googling, read all of the documentation I found and I tried if I can achieve the following with Page Actions but no luck.

I would like to add text and icon to the right side of the omnibox (inside of it) from an Edge extension, like the shopping/coupons extension does: [image]

Is there a public API for doing that?

Answer (score 1):

First, the example you mentioned in your post is not an extension. It's an [Edge built-in feature](https://blogs.windows.com/windowsexperience/2020/11/19/finish-up-that-holiday-shopping-with-new-features-from-microsoft-edge-and-bing/). Then I doubt that if extensions can achieve the same as the Edge built-in feature.

Second, I search Chrome API reference, especially the [chrome.omnibox](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/omnibox/) API. I find that there's no API can meet your requirements.

In a conclusion, I think there's no such API and it's not feasible to achieve what you want through extensions.